# Menu does not appear while viewing a node of a particular content type

Tags: 7, routes

I've a singular problem.

On my installation I've several content types and I've a menu that appears on every page.
The problem is that on every node of a certain content type (and ONLY with nodes of this content type) the menu isn't displayed.

This happens if I set the block with the default way to place blocks and also if I try to place it with context.

I've tried also to add on the page.tpl.php this code:

```
$menu = menu_navigation_links("menu-name-here");
print theme('links', $menu);
```

Links from "menu-name-here" are printed on EVERY page, but are not printed in nodes of one content type.
I've not tpl for nodes..

It seems that on this page functions to get links from menu don't works: any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any other template files in your theme that start with `page--node`?

Comment: No, nothing. And however the block placed with context does not appear. I have not tried to place another menu